# Filer in filter (vertical and horizontal) in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I have a table where the column headers are dates and the row key are letters. the table cells contain values between 1 to 9.

I wish to return a list of the letters based on a date and a value threshold.

f.e. return a list of letters where date=X and (on that day) the values are above 5)

I have attached an editable spreadsheet below
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oW7mo3az3a_4dTCEtKauF1qVPEDKb8ydaCLFiHcaWfI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
=FILTER(B3:B24,INDEX(B3:G24,0,MATCH(J3,B2:G2,0))>K3)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! worked like a charm!